# How to run a background process with mod perl

Tags: perl, apache2, mod-perl

I am using perl to return data sets in XML. Now I have come across a situation where I need to run some clean up after sending a dataset to the client. But some where, in the chain of mod perl and Apache, the output gets held onto until my method returns.

I have attempted to clear the buffers with commands like.

```
$| =1;
STDOUT->flush(); # flush the buffer so the content is sent to the client and the finish hook can carry on, with out delaying the return.
if ($mod_perl_io){
    $mod_perl_io->rflush;
}
```

Yet I still get no output until my method returns. I then found out that my browser my be waiting for the connection to close and found that setting the content type in the header should fix this.

```
rint $cgi->header(-type => "text/plain; charset=UTF-8", -cookie => $config->{'cookie'});
```

Still no luck, in fact I had always been sending the correct headers.

So I though the best option is to simply start a new thread and let my method return. But when I create a new thread.

```
use threads ('yield',
             'stack_size' => 64*4096,
             'exit' => 'threads_only',
             'stringify');
my $thr = threads->create('doRebuild', $dbconnect, $dbusername, $dbpassword,  $bindir);
sub doRebuild {
my ($dbconnect, $dbusername, $dbpassword,  $bindir ) = @_;
1;
}
```

I get a segfault

> [Fri Feb 22 10:16:47 2013] [notice] child pid 26076 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

From what I have read this is done by mod perl to ensure thread safe operation. Not sure if this is correct.

So I thought I'd try using {exe }

```
{exec   'perl', "$bindir/rebuild_needed_values.pl", qw('$dbconnect' '$dbusername' '$dbpassword');}
```

From what I gather this is taking over the process from mod perl and not letting it return anything.

I know this isn't as specific as a question on stack overflow should be, but this sort of thing must be a common problem how have others solved it?

Comment: Did you try [`fork`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use fork(), however I like to recommend http://gearman.org/ for background processing.

A solution like Gearman is much better, because your background process is not in Apache's process chain.

Your process will survive an Apache restart if implemented using gearman. It is also more secure, as the Gearman environment can be run in a chroot jail.

A nice side effect of using Gearman is that your background process becomes callable from other machines and even other languages.

Gearman makes it easy to collect the data from your process at a later time as well, and you can feed back progress information to your web app rather easily.